# Change plus ( + ) sign to bar ( | ) sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just wanting to create something that when clicked will hide or show the text below the item. THE QUESTION that I have is "how would I change the `+` sign into a `|` sign when the `h1` is clicked.  The code:

HTML:

```
<h1>+ Welcome</h1>
<p>This is the welcome greeting</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    display: none; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();              
    } else {
        $('p').show();      
    }
});
```

#### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfh96k87/)

Comment: You could place the symbol in a css psuedo element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your `+` to an element and change it:

HTML

```
<h1><span>+</span> Welcome</h1>
<p>This is the welcome greeting</p>
```

jQuery

```
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();
        $(this).find('span').text('+');
    } else {
        $('p').show();
        $(this).find('span').text('|');      
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/53Le63ar/).

Comment: I like this one because it allows for a more dynamic change, regardless of what the h1 states

Answer (score 4):

Since it's the `h1` that's clicked, you can use `$(this)` inside your function.

```
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();
        $(this).text('+ Welcome');
    } else {
        $('p').show();
        $(this).text('| Welcome');    
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqf5sd39/)

Comment: i like this solution because it doesn't require changing the markup.

Comment: If that's a real requirement, then fair enough, but if you have control of the markup, it *should* be changed. Semantically, it's not very useful. "+ Welcome" is not the name of the section.

Comment: I have to agree with you, better would be to add the `+` with a `:before` pseudo class, so it is style, and not actual content.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `::before` pseudo-element:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is the welcome greeting</p>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper > h1:before {
  content: '|';
}
.wrapper.hide > h1:before {
  content: '+';
}
.wrapper.hide > p {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(".wrapper").addClass('hide').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $(this);
    $wrapper.children('h1').on('click', function() {
        $wrapper.toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhc1ychk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the content of a tag with `.text()` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/text/)):

```
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();
        $(this).text("+ Welcome");
    } else {
        $('p').show();
        $(this).text("| Welcome");
    }
});
```

However, as others pointed out, this would be easier if you moved the special character inside its own `<span>` element. Also consider giving an `id` to the elements you want to interact with, as `$("p")` will match *all* the `p` elements in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the "+" inside it's own `<span>` tag.

**HTML:**

`<h1>
     <span id='symbol' class="plus">+</span> Welcome
</h1>`

**jQuery:**

```
$("h1").click(function(){
    var span = $("#symbol");

    if(span.hasClass("plus")){
        span.html("|");
        span.removeClass("plus");
        span.addClass("pipe");
    }else{
        span.html("+");
        span.removeClass("pipe");
        span.addClass("plus");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

## [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/56a91qe0/)

Here is your code

### HTML

```
<h1><span>+</span> Welcome</h1>
<p>This is the welcome greeting</p>
```

### JavaScript

```
$( "h1" ).click(function() {
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();
        $(this).find('span').text('+');
    } else {
        $('p').show();      
        $(this).find('span').text('|');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the markup and want the flexibility of being able to change the other text in the h1 without modifying your JavaScript, then using the JavaScript [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function could be a alternative.

```
$( "h1" ).on('click', function() {
    var heading = $(this).html();
    if ($('p').is(':visible')){
        $('p').hide();
        $(this).html(heading.replace('|', '+')); 
    } else {
        $('p').show();
        $(this).html(heading.replace('+', '|')); 
    }
});
```